# SSH docker container issue after running Apache on Alpine

Tags: apache, docker, ssh, alpine-linux

I have an issue in my SSH session with a docker container.
Actually can't execute any command because of a running process that never gives me hand on the terminal, see output:

```
[Thu Apr 02 19:39:46.056749 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 02 19:39:46.057465 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Dockerfile install Apache on Alpine and ends:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Any hint how I can get my SSH session working and gives me hand to execute other commands? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually moving command from my dockerfile to the procfile provided by my hosting provider solved the issue.
Dockerfile after this change:

```
FROM alpine
# install apache
# other installation requirements
EXPOSE 80
# commented the line below
# ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And moved the last instruction to Procfile. After this change the process will be a service published from my container and not an entrypoint that will be executed each time the image built or restarted.

Answer (score 1):

The container paradigm does not promote usage of things like ssh servers. The core concept is that you are only hosting a single isolated process inside the container, in your case 'httpd'.

in other words, there is no ssh server running inside the apache container, it is only hosting the web server process.

You can use a command like `docker exec <container_name> <command>`, to execute another process in the same container. For example:

```sh
docker exec myhttpd ls -la
```

Which will list the content of the configured working directory in the container.

`docker exec` will connect the stdout and stderr in your current terminal session to the stdout and stderr of the container, and execute your command in the environment of the container.

This is a good solution for trouble shooting and trying things out. But look for alternatives if you are seeking to permanently change the environment of your contained application. Such as using the Dockerfile.

If you supply some more information about your usecase, I will be happy to make a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Andreas for the response. Actually docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash gives me hand for other commands in my local machine (docker version v2.2), but after hosting this container in a cloud platform and try to ssh remotely I got this output.

Comment: What command is it that you want to pass to the container? Or what type of command? Are you hosting it with some container service, or do you have a virtual host with docker on it?

Comment: It's a container service. I don't have hands to type anything actually even ls command. Is it something i need to change in the command httpd to execute it in the backend for example? is that possible actually?

Comment: It does not work like that with docker - there is no "backend" scenario. You may be thinking of running the httpd process as a service, but that is not how docker works. With docker, the process should be in the foreground in the container, as it is actually the only process in the container. If you need to change something in the container, you would either do it in the Dockerfile, and redeploy it or use the docker/application API to change the environment. If you have usecases where you need to do changes inside your container often, then docker may not be the technology for your usecase.

Comment: Additionally, if you have a usecase where you need to inspect the data that the container is housing - then consider mapping the volume out of the container. Then you can poke around the data whereever you have mapped it.

Comment: Your idea is very clear and understood, and my use case is not changing something in the container (as you said writing it in Dockerfile and push it will do the thing). Actually the hosting provider am using gives me ability to ssh an ephemeral copy so i can for example try something for development, in another container ssh works just fine (entrypoint in that case is apache-wrapper and using ubuntu), maybe I should think about changing the entrypoint for this image. actually that should be my first question here :)

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Lorenzen for your feedbacks. Actually i could resolve my issue please check my answer below.